# Slow preformance during replaceScene

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I'm facing a performance issue whenever the code reach "replaceScene". It happens only in the Play Scene. So after the game is over, I display a score, and then, it's time for CCDirector to do replaceScene in order to go back to the main menu.

After waiting for around 20 seconds then it finally display the main menu. But somehow this is not right, player will feel that the game suddenly hang. Then I tried to put some animation like preloader, it happens the same, the preloader picture did animate a while then suddenly stop, and I think due to the same issue triggered by replaceScene, although still it'll display the main menu scene. Care to give some tips how to speed up the releasing of all the objects which no longer needed.

Hoping to get a solution from experts here. Thanks.

Here is my code :

```
............
//button at the score pop up sprite

CCMenuItem *btContinue = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:BTCONTINUE 
                                                selectedImage:BTCONTINUE_ON 
                                                       target:self 
                                                     selector:@selector(goLoader)];
btContinue.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
btContinue.position = ccp(340, 40);

CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:btContinue, nil];
menu.position = CGPointZero;

[self addChild:menu z:ZPOPUP_CONTENT];

//prepare the loader, but set visible to NO first
CCSprite *loaderBg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:LOADER_FINISH];
loaderBg.anchorPoint = ccp(0,0);
loaderBg.position = ccp(0,0);
loaderBg.visible = NO;
[self addChild:loaderBg z:ZLOADER_BG tag:TAG_LOADER_BG];
NSLog(@"prepare loader finish");

//animate loader
CCSprite *loaderPic = [[CCSprite alloc] initWithSpriteFrame:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] 
                                                          spriteFrameByName:LOADER]];    
loaderPic.anchorPoint = ccp(0.5,0.5);
loaderPic.position = ccp(200,35);
loaderPic.visible = NO;
[self addChild:loaderPic z:ZLOADER_PIC tag:TAG_LOADER_PIC];

[loaderPic runAction:[CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.05f angle:10.0f]]];
}

-(void)goLoader {
NSLog(@"goMainMenuScene");
CCSprite *tmpBg = (CCSprite *) [self getChildByTag:TAG_LOADER_BG];
if (tmpBg != nil)
    tmpBg.visible = YES;

CCSprite *tmpPic = (CCSprite *) [self getChildByTag:TAG_LOADER_PIC];
if (tmpPic != nil)
    tmpPic.visible = YES;

double time = 2.0;
id delay = [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration: time];
id proceed = [CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(goMainMenuScene)];
id seq = [CCSequence actions: delay, proceed, nil];
[self runAction:seq];
}

-(void)goMainMenuScene {
[[GameManager sharedGameManager] runSceneWithID:SCENE_MAIN_MENU];
}
```

Comment: You are doing some heavy computations on the main thread. Adding loading animation won't work unless you determine what is causing all this lag, and move that code and execute it on a background thread. The best way to find the problem is to use **time profiler** from the **Xcode Instruments** tools.

Comment: how much memory do you use? i assume that you are loading huge amount of resourses into memory(sounds, art) in the main thread.

Comment: What's the best way of getting the info of how much memory that I use in that scene?

Comment: @Mazyod:thx, I'm newbie to instruments, will definitely try it out later, but how do everybody else make the preloader pic then?

Comment: @Wes: They do as I explained. They move the code that takes a lot of time to execute to a background thread. `[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadAssets) withObject:nil];`.

Comment: @Wes: And btw, I would be worried about memory if I were you. If the game hangs **after** the scene disappears, that means you have memory problems. But since your code is hanging as soon as you call `replaceScene:`, I am pretty sure memory is not the main issue here.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely the new scene, and whatever happens in the new scene's and its child node's init methods. Loading resource files can take quite a while. If you defer doing this into onEnter you might see better results. But 20 seconds, that's a lot. Check what you're doing that takes THIS long. I bet it's loading a gross amount of resources, or loading them in an extremely inefficient way. JPG files are known to load very slowly, if you use JPG convert them to PNG.